# How to hide the from email address from the receiver in log4j.xml?

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I want to send an email to the user, in which the user should not be able to view the actual from address. Here is my log4j.xml. I need to replace "username@gmail.com" to "no-reply@gmail.com".

```
 <appender name="mailAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
    <param name="BufferSize" value="512" />
    <param name="SMTPHost" value="smtp.gmail.com" /> 
    <param name="SMTPPort" value="465" />
    <param name="SMTPUsername" value="username@gmail.com" />
    <param name="SMTPPassword" value="password" />
    <param name="SMTPProtocol" value="smtpprotocol" />  
    <param name="From" value="username@gmail.com" />
    <!-- <param name="From" value="no-reply@gmail.com" /> -->
    <param name="To" value="toaddress@gmail.com" />
    <param name="Subject" value="Welcome" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}]%n%n%-5p%n%n%c%n%n%m%n%n" />
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="error" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="fatal" />
    </filter>
</appender>

<root>
    <priority value="warn" />
    <appender-ref ref="mailAppender" />
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks in advance..

Comment: Gmail wont let you do that, the sender's email will always be send along

Answer (score 0):

Use Masking for Sensetive information while logging using log4j . Below are few links for your help to masking in log4j.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6PEW_9.5.0/com.ibm.help.custom.basics.doc/customization/Cstm_mask_info_using_log4j.html

https://gomtiprabha.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/masking-sensitive-info-or-data-in-logs/

Comment: OP does not want to mask in the log but in the email that will be send

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other possibility, other than masking?

Comment: You can use below code to hide some extend .   messageMail.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myrealadress@abc.com", "no-reply@abc.com"));     But  if you are using a free public mail server (Gmail, Yahoo, etc.) it will usually force your message to contain your real address, to prevent you from sending spam with a fake address